# How to search Powershell array for specific strings and use this result in a copy-item -include script

Tags: arrays, powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to create a synchronization script in Powershell so that my applications in MDT are being copied on a regular basis to our main file server, based on the folder name (in MDT, applications are in one folder, where our main server has applications split depending on the department who uses them).

From what I read on the web, the best way would be to populate an array with "Get-ChildItem", which I kinda figured how to do (see code below).

After the array is populated though, I don't know how to search that array for specific results, nor do I know how to use those results with copy-item.

In a nutshell, here's what I need to do: Build an array using "Get-ChildItem", query the resulting array for specific folders, and have those folders be copied to specific destinations.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$arr = Get-ChildItem \\slmtl-wds02.domain.inc\deploymentshare$\applications | 
   Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
   Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
$sourcepath = \\slmtl-wds02.domain.inc\deploymentshare$\applications
$destSLARC = \\slmtl-fs01.domain.inc\folder\it_services\private\software\service_desk\pc\SLARCMTL
$destSLMTL = \\slmtl-fs01.domain.inc\folder\it_services\private\software\service_desk\pc\SLMTL
$destSLGLB = \\slmtl-fs01.domain.inc\folder\it_services\private\software\service_desk\pc\SLGLB
$destSLTECH = \\slmtl-fs01.domain.inc\folder\it_services\private\software\service_desk\pc\SLTECH
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sourceLocation = "c:\analysis\"
$targetLocation = "c:\analysisCopy\"
$included = @("folder1", "folder2")

$result = @()
foreach ($i in $included){
    $result += get-ChildItem $sourceLocation -filter $i | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
}
$result | foreach-Object { copy-item $_.FullName -Destination $targetLocation -Recurse}
```

Comment: YES! This works perfectly.
If my memory serves me good, if I want it to overwrite what is there, I just have to add -Force after the -Recurse, right ?

Comment: Yes, if you add -force, it will overwrite any files that already exist in the target instead of throwing exceptions.  However, it will not delete existing files from the target that no longer exist at the source, so if you want that to happen you might just want to delete the target first.

Comment: Nah, mostly this script will serve to simply copy what I update on our MDT server to our main file server, where every tech from all the offices have access. So _keeping track_ of the older stuff is not really a problem.
Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: That ended up being up giant-ass script, but in the end, all works fines. Here's what the final result looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ax3h9r6318k9k41/MDT_to_FS01.ps1?dl=0

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there are ways to eliminate some of that code - my answer wasn't optimal to begin with - but it's probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works change the path D:\ to your desired path enter the name of folder you looking for

```
$Keyword=[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter your Query") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
Get-ChildItem D:\ -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $fasle -and $_.Name -match "$keyword"} | Copy-Item -Destination d:\test
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what I want to do.
I do not want to cherry-pick specific file-types or file names. The whole process is folder-based, not-file based.
I need to query a folder to have all the subfolder names, and then query the result for specific names, and add those result to a copy-item so they can be copied. 

Your solution simply says "Search this folder for those file types/names, and copy them here". I know how to use Robocopy, but it can't do what I need it to do (well, yes, but I'd have so many exceptions it just wouldn't make sense).

Comment: check it now modified the answer

Comment: @jacksh I think he wants to search on multiple keywords.